Running a new Electric line to new metal garage
I am a moving to TN & working on my own new home.
I am having a 20 x 20 x 9h steel garage erected in 6 weeks, and want to run simple power to it for basic service.
The new home has a 200A service and 6 open slots on the panel.
The panel is 10 feet from the outside wall and the detached garage is 16 additional feet from the Wiring exit on the home.
The garage will have:

A 3/4 hp belt drive opener.
240 watts of interior LED lighting on a wall switch.
An outdoor hardwired motion sensor LED 20W light.
Three 15A basic interior Wall outlets for a battery charger, drop light, or box fan, nothing big.

This is what I'm thinking...
A pounded-in 48" grounding rod with a copper ground strap screwed directly to the all-steel building frame.
A single buried 12/3 feeder from the house to the garage.
A wall box at the outside of the house.
PVC waterproofed piping out of the house box to a 24" deep trench, and over to the garage.
PVC pipe out of the ground and into the garage.
A waterproofed route into an inside regular square garage wall box to receive the new wire into the garage.
One 12/3 feed for the lights and opener.
One 12/3 feed for the outlets.
I am expecting more than one correction, and want to do this properly & very efficiently.
My logical mind wants to overbuild always, however, I do not want this to look like this space was intended for a shop...being said, I realize the space may need to handle a small 'pancake' portable compressor if ever needed, but little else. There is a 20A GFI outlet, 20 feet from the garage for additional outdoor power access... The EV 'future' access is a good point, as there is a good chance we may sell this place a few years down the road...SO, I am PVC piping the entire run now, 3/4"?. I would rather install 2 small sub-boxes (one for now and one for someone else later), than one large box.  Would this small SqD model be in play (Model #QO2L30SCP)? I have 6 open spaces on my main house breaker 200A service. How many spaces should I use? What wire should I pipe to the garage?  I am still considering using BX from the sub-box through the metal frame garage. 12ga. wire with 15A outlets.

12 gauge wire limits you to only 20 amps.  Right now probably enough, next year who knows.  Breakers usually can handle about two larger wire gauge size.  20x20 building could handle a few tools.  Should do a load calculation on your main panel to see how much power is available to send to the shed.  You can oversize now and not use it, or need to increase everything in a few years and pay extra.

12/3 is black/red/white/ground. If going for the low-end install it makes some sense to use 12/3 for the feeder, as you can run a multi-wire branch Circuit. There's no point in using 12/3 for your outlets, lights, or opener; 12/2 (black/white/ground) should work for all those things.  There's good reason to

...consider having a sub-panel at the garage and a 15A breaker in it for the lights, which can then use 14 AWG which costs less and is easier to work with.

You're asking and implying a number of distinct questions here, which makes your post off topic. Please see [ask].

Off topic? Just guiding past suggestions not following my desired goal.

Well, you need a disconnect (switch or breaker) for the garage, at the garage.
Also the garage outlets need to be GFCI protected. That can be done at the feed breaker, if you like. It will be less expensive to do in the garage.
While a 12/3 direct burial cable might be adequate for your minimal needs, the short distance means that putting in a proper conduit the whole way is not going to cost a lot, and it's far more resistant to damage than stubs into and out of the ground with 15 feet of unprotected cable between them. It might even come in less expensive to run conduit and THWN wires than cable.
"Waterproofed" or not, every exterior conduit is defined as a wet location, so the wires or cables in it need to be wet rated. If not using conduit in the trench, the cable must be direct-burial rated.
These days (even if you don't personally think you'll get one, today) it's wise to plan for the possibility that an electric vehicle charging circuit might be wanted in the garage at some future time. Using conduit means you don't have to put that in place now, but makes it easy to in the future if it's ever wanted.

Subpanel
While you can run a single circuit (12/3 is a 20A 240V/120V MWBC), that really isn't a good idea for a large building. You can do a lot with a 20' x 20' building. Anything from a very nice workshop to a small apartment (accessory dwelling unit = ADU) to a very nice home/small business office space. Obviously some of these (particularly an ADU) will require plumbing, but even without any plumbing there are still many different things you can do that can require many separate circuits.
The best solution is a subpanel. But even better is to get a "main" panel (in quotes because you won't actually use it as a main panel) because that provides a main disconnect switch (which otherwise is a separate item, as noted already in another answer) and typically provides lots of spaces for separate circuits at a low cost.
As one example, Eaton BR 100A 20 space from Home Depot, for around $100 you get a panel that includes:

100A main breaker
2 20A single breakers - for receptacles or lights
1 30A double breaker - for water heater, HVAC or EV charging, among other things

and that leaves plenty of room for additional circuits in the future. If you never add anything else, the $100 is not that bad just for the first few circuits and a main disconnect.
There are smaller options. I would consider an 8 space (not "circuit") panel the absolute minimum. Why? Because that gives you two spaces for a backfed "main" breaker, two spaces for the immediate needs (receptacles + motor; lights) and two spaces for expansion (EVSE or more receptacles). A 2 space would be a big mistake because you could power the necessary two circuits today but would become a throwaway (waste of money and require more rewiring work to install a replacement) or be used only as a disconnect (but if so, might as well just use a typical 60A-rated unfused disconnect switch and add a subpanel when needed later).
Also keep in mind that any subpanel requires a 30" x 36" space in front kept open/empty for access. Same whether it is a tiny panel or a huge panel.
Even a large panel can be fed by 12/3. Just because it has a 100A main breaker doesn't mean you have to feed it 100A. So look at the pricing and I really think a mid-size panel - say 12 to 20 spaces (not "circuits") - makes a lot of sense, providing a good balance between total initial cost and future upgrade possibilities.
Note that even a large subpanel will only require 2 spaces in the main panel. (Well, exception for 150A or 200A feed as those are often 4-space breakers, but that's not the situation here.) So the key is spaces in the subpanel - for additional circuits when needed - and not in the main panel (you have 6, you need 2, that leaves 4 spaces for future expansion in the main building).
A few additional items:
Feed Wire/Conduit
As already noted in another answer, run conduit with wires instead of cable. That lets you upgrade in the future. In additional, conduit does not need to buried as deep as cable. In fact, if you use rigid metal conduit then you can (in most places, for residential use, provided it is not under a driveway) bury it 6" down, which is a lot easier than 24".
If you install conduit, install larger than you currently need. For example, you could use 8 AWG aluminum for a 40A feed and use 3/4" PVC or RMC conduit. But that would not leave much room for expansion. On the other hand, if you used 1-1/4" conduit you would have enough capacity to later replace with up to 1 AWG aluminum (3 wires - hot/hot/neutral) + 6 AWG aluminum (1 wire - ground).
As far as how large a feed to install now, that depends on two Load Calculations, one to determine how much excess capacity is available in the main panel (that's the maximum you can do) and another to determine how much capacity you actually need in the new building (that's the minimum you can do). The feed breaker is what determines the feed size and the wire can be a size to match that breaker or any size larger. Larger wire generally costs more, but can make sense depending on what is available at various price points and the possibility of future expansion.
Based on the initial question, I'd go with a 30A feed breaker (double breaker in the main panel) with 4 wires (hot, hot, neutral, ground) x 10 AWG copper (good for up to 35A) or aluminum (good for up to 30A). That will, realistically, allow for 4 x 20A 120V circuits with no changes, which works unless/until you add heavy equipment or EVSE or HVAC.
Ground Rods
Not sure where you got 48" from. Normally ground rods are 8 feet long, and normally you need two of them, at least 6 feet apart. The wire connecting the ground rods should go to your subpanel, not to the building. The subpanel will be physically mounted on the building so the building will be grounded - and I am pretty sure an extra wire for that purpose is perfectly fine. But the main ground wire, going to the ground rods, has to terminate at the subpanel.
Receptacles
Don't short-change yourself on receptacles.

Three 15A basic interior Wall outlets

Normal residential code for most finished rooms in a house requires a receptacle every 12' along each wall. That doesn't apply here. But I think it is a good idea for usability. Assuming one wall is mostly door, that would mean probably 2 on each of the other 3 walls = 6 receptacles, and each would typically be a 15A duplex receptacle. Put those receptacles on at least one 20A circuit (no problem with 15A receptacles on 20A circuits). But I would actually recommend at least two circuits. Done well, the wiring will be pretty much the same but that will give you a lot more flexibility. And more receptacles/more circuits is perfectly fine - after all, you'll have plenty of spaces in the subpanel to use for additional circuits.
Just remember that all of these receptacles will need GFCI protection. That can be done at the breaker, but it is almost always quite a bit cheaper (and just as safe) to install a GFCI/receptacle as the first receptacle in each chain.

Your recommendation for receptacle spacing isn't bad, but the 12' rule is derived from 210.52(A) for  kitchen, family room, dining room, living room, parlor, library, den, sunroom, bedroom, recreation room, or similar rooms.  the requirements applicable are in 210.52(G) Basements, Garages, and Accessory Buildings. https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#210.52_(G)

Thanks for the help. I may go with 4 outlets, 2 on each side, 10' apart.

I do not want a major box here.  This is only a parking and light storage garage, nothing more, ever.  Biggest deal is lighting, it gets really dark out here.  Will I need a separate disconnect if I have a breaker box?  The ground rod may be an issue...I could not get a 3-foot rebar stake pounded in as I hit bedrock in three different locations withing 24" of the surface.  Thanks Again, Dean

If you have a breaker box (subpanel) then you do not need a separate disconnect, provided the box either (a) has a main breaker or (b) has a backfed breaker used as an effective main breaker or (c) has 6 or fewer "throws" to turn everything off (which would be the case as long as you have 6 or fewer circuits, and in some cases even with more than 6 circuits. So instead of a $ 100 mid-size "main panel", you could use a $35 - $50 "small subpanel", though the "free" breakers in a typical "main panel package deal" helps cover part of the difference.

Keep in mind that in the long-term, garage will mean EV-charging for most (not all) people, so having the capability to add that easily later (which is the case with a subpanel and a decent feeder size) is a big plus. (Don't add the actual charging equipment now, that would be a waste).

As far as ground rods - check with your local building/electrical permit department. The answer could be "3 feet is good enough" or "You need to drill a hole" or something else.

Edited main Q above...I have a good inspector, who I helped solve a minor local issue. He will be consulted here.  These codes might be 'loose', I still want this parking garage to be proper.

Some comments that may seem obvious, or maybe not.
You need to use UF or USE for direct burial cable.
Direct Burial needs 18" of cover above wire.
A disconnect switch is required at garage, a dpst light switch is minimum requirement.
All receptacles will need gfci protection. I believe the current interpretation is even the opener requires protection, but the reset has to be accessible. So feed with a gfci breaker or off load terminals of an accessible gfci receptacle. It may be worth calling your local inspector to verify local adoption or exceptions to relevant NEC sections.
For a single 12/3 multiwire branch circuit feeder as you have described additional ground rods are not required. Probably at least one full length 8' rod to the disconnect box would be a good idea.
You said 12/3 to lights and receptacles. Maybe there's terminology problem. In "cables" (as opposed to cords) the ground isn't included in the count, you only need 12/2 for most lights and receptacles. 12/3 feeder to the garage (two hots feed by two adjacent handle tied breaker spaces) can be broken out after the required disconnect as two separate 12/2 120v circuits.
Your minimalist approach is understood, but if a customer or friend wanted me to install that I would refuse on the basis of reputation protection. Just a compressor or extension cord and a worm drive saw could leave you in the dark. You can avoid brownouts and voltage drop losses by running  a 10/3 as a 30A 240v feeder to a 6 space panel. You can use two spaces as a backfed disconnect, and 4 spaces for 120v circuits. One circuit breaker for lights, one dedicated for opener (neither of which will draw full demand), then two circuits for receptacle outlets. If you do this then ground rods would also be required.
